# Simple transformerless 3.7VDC to 220VAC

Tags: inverter, transformerless

I am looking for a circuit design that could be capable of inverting 3.7VDC to 220 VAC. The maximum current draw is below 50 milliamps, and this circuit shouldn't have problem like voltage drop as result of low voltage in battery.

The frequency must be in normal range 50-60 Hz,50 milliamps is the peak, and I intend to design it with SMD components. Can a DC to AC circuit be designed without a transformer with these specs?

Comment: Is 220-330vac an adjustable range or is it 275 +- 55? What frequency? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Can you give us more information? At what frequency do you want the "220-330vac" to be? Did you really mean 220 - 330 or was that a typo for 220 - 230, a normal mains voltage? What batteries do you propose using? I very much doubt this can be done without a transformer.

Comment: We need more information: frequecy out? what you mean by that voltage range (variable or is it a tollerance you're looking at)? is the 50mA constant or peak? 50mA at 330V is 16.5W, that is nearly 5Amps out of the battery even at 90% effeicency, are you sure the battery can do that?

Comment: Does it really need to be transformerless?

Comment: Simple and DC to a sine wave at non-signal power levels don't really go together, on top of the low voltage to high voltage.

Comment: You really, really ought to use a transformer.

Comment: To get 50 mA at 220 V AC, you need more than 3 A at 3.7 V DC. Is the battery capable to deliver that much current as long as you want it to operate? With an efficiency of about 75 % you need over 4 A.

Comment: You don't want to design one, you want _us_ to design one and then give it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely this would work well without a transformer. A circuit can I can that think of that meets your only smt requirement is the voltage doubler, which uses only diodes and capacitors.

But the voltage doubler only has efficiencies of ~75% on a good day. And to get from 3.7V to 220V you would need to double the voltage at least 50 times, which would yield efficiencies of less than 0.5E-6 which is dismal, since more than 1 Megawatt would be needed to generate  50mA at 220V. In addition to that the circuit would take up a large area. And that's only to get the voltage up to a level where it can be chopped to yield a sine wave. Point being is circuits using only capacitors and diodes are going to be lossy and prohibitively expensive from an energy standpoint.

An inverter circuit with a transformer is a better way. There's plenty of information by searching for DC to AC inverter circuit.

If he only need to build one of these you could potentially buy a 12 volt inverter and just set the voltage up from 3.7 volts to 12 volts, which would be a little bit more lossy because you have two 'boost' stages versus one transformer, but it might be harder to find a transformer with the number of turns that you need to go from 3.7 volts to 220 volts.

Comment: Voltage multipliers put out DC. A Cockcroft-Walton (Greinacher) multiplier would put out DC with some ripple.  A Villard multiplier would put out what looks like AC, but with a DC offset of about half the peak to peak value of the AC.  Regardless, the impedance of such a multiplier would be insanely high.

Comment: with is the smallest transformer size that i can use? any schematic in your mind ?

Comment: I forgot to add the part about the rest of the inverter circuit

Comment: what is the smallest transformer? How small do you want it and how much money do you want to pay? There are a number of solutions depending on your specifications.

Comment: The size of the transformer depends on the used frequency and the power needed at the secondary side. Of course there should be enough space for the windings. To get a small transformer you need a high frequency, low power and a thin wire. But with a thin wire you get a high resistivity of the windings and a low efficiency due to the copper losses.

Comment: Basically you'd be getting into boost DC DC converter design

Comment: Can't I just use the transformer inside a 5vdc phone charger?  Size of those transformers is perfect. There are a lot of transfer designing websites, I would be happy if anyone mention a good one, tnx
Your comments were insightful.

Comment: In short: no, you have to do a boost converter design with a switcher

Comment: Cherry-picking: 3.7V to 220V would require to double the voltage between 6 and 7 times, not 50.

Comment: The "dismal 0.5E-6" feels more sensational than factual, and doesn't really seem justified without saying that there are much better ways of doing this [Characteristics of a symmetrical Cockcroft-Walton power supply of 50 Hz 1.2 MV/50 mA](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215471773_Characteristics_of_a_symmetrical_Cockcroft-Walton_power_supply_of_50_Hz_12_MV50_mA) and [A High-Efficiency CMOS Voltage Doubler](https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/syiYQesroOAhUCBC.pdf) Granted you'd have to do some work to drive a Cockcroft-Walton starting from 3.7 VDC instead of mains AC.

Comment: My intentiontion was to be sensational, the crockroft doubler uses a transformer, the OP did not want to use one

Comment: @VoltageSpike You don't need a transformer to drive a  Cockroft-Walton from DC. Capacitor coupling of switched DC works fine. Been there, done that. However, starting from 3.7V is pretty tough.